# Spring Exception: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have the following spring-config xml file, which is generating the exception shown in the title of my post:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:int-jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jpa"
xmlns:int-sftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp"
xmlns:file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
xmlns:int-xml="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jpa/spring-integration-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp/spring-integration-sftp.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml/spring-
integration-xml.xsd"> 

<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter
    id="resultsProcessor"
    channel="responseChannel"
    auto-startup="true"
    named-query="OpenRecords"
    expect-single-result="true"
    delete-after-poll="false"
    entity-class="foo.Request">
        <int:poller 
        id="responsePoller" 
        fixed-rate="5000" 
        max-messages-per-poll="10">
        </int:poller>
</int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>

</beans>
```

The code I provide above has other elements removed from it, and some of the fields renamed to simplify the example. That is why you see some schema and namespace information at the top that does not apply to the example as presented.

The error actually takes place at the line corresponding to **entity-class="foo.Request">**, but I don't know that there is anything inherently wrong with that line, but simply that is where the termination ">" is. In other words, if I removed that line and put the ">" after **delete-after-poll="false"**, the error would be there instead.

Am I perhaps missing a namespace and/or schema location definition? Alternatively, could it be a missing deployment dependency? Grateful for any ideas. Thank you.

Comment: What version of Spring Integration are you using? The current version is 5.0.2; that attribute was introduced in 2.2, nearly six years ago. Do you have the spring-integration-jpa jar on the classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jpa` to your dependencies. You simply missing a jar in your classpath

Comment: thank you Oleg. I was indeed missing this dependency in my pom. This fixed my problem.

Comment: to clarify, I simply needed:<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>